# runtime complexity

Tags: computational-complexity

i want to Order these runtime complexitys ascending.
I tried to transform this and made a first try in ordering them which you can find behind the -->

- $log4711$ --> 1.
- $log^4(n)$ --> 2.
- $log(n^4)$ --> $4log(n)$ --> 3.
- $\sqrt[4]{n}$ --> $n^{\frac{1}{4}}$ --> 4.
- $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ --> 5.
- $9^{log_3(n)}$ --> $n^2$ --> 6.
- $e^{\frac{1}{3}n}$ --> 7.
- $(n-1)!$ --> 8.

I am not sure if my solution is correct and how to transform $log^4(n)$

Best Regards

Comment: Looks pretty good, but if $\log^4n$ means $(\log n)^4$ then it exceeds $4\log n$.

Comment: Reordered the list to your numeration, so to check order we don't have to iterate through it for every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\log n$ growth infinitely, $\log^4n$ growth faster than $\log n$, and so lines $2$ and $3$ should be swapped.

If you know that $\log n$ growth slower than any power, than to compare $\log^4$ and $\sqrt[4]n$ you can say that $\log n$ growth slower than $\sqrt[16]n$, and then take $4$th power of both sides.

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure what $log^4(n)$ meant. I think like Gerry Myerson commented it does mean $(log n)^4$.